# How to stick Tabs with Collapsing ToolBar Layout and TabLayout below ToolBar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am having collapsing ToolbarLayout with TabLayout, everything is working fine except my Tabs are not getting sticked below toolbar on scroll up.

Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/carouselLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xlarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:id="@+id/content_title"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Please help me how can I achieve this. Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />
```

Try This..It may help you..